# Properties in Liquibase change scripts

Tags: migration, maven-3, liquibase

What's the best way to have propeties filled out in a Liquibase SQL file?

I wan't to use this for specifying things like tablespaces and schemas. Ideally it would be done run-time with Liquibase, but Maven filtering could be an option too.

Comment: Hi Anders, I am also facing a similar issue, Have you found a work around for this? and can you give the JIRA link for this issue?

Comment: Seems it was fixed in Liquibase 3.1.0 :) https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-641

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liquibase supports changelog parameters (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html) is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks, I figured that after a little while. The problem was that I was trying to substitute variables in SQL files. That doesn't work, for now it only works inside the sql tag in XML. There's an issue registered for it though, so should hopefully be fixed soon.